Effective techniques to train my ear to identify the tonal center of the music
What are some effective techniques to train my ear to hear the tonal center of a musical excerpt?
I am trying to isolate this skill: 


Specifically, suggestions for methods that don’t require other people / heavy setup will be much appreciated as I am often on the road and trying to find ways to leverage flights and waiting times for quick ear training.
Thanks!

Welcome. Asking for resources such as this are not part of the site's remit. You could do what I've done for the last 60+ yrs, and simply take recordings, and work out what you need by listening. Good luck!

Ok, I’ll rephrase it to not ask about relevant tools.

I think it depends on a few factors. For instance, do you just want to be able to sing the tonal centre, or are you aiming to know its name (D, Bb, etc). Your ears can help you identify the sound of the tonal centre, but to know its name requires (additionally) perfect pitch, or an app (or instrument).
Also, as they progress, musical excerpts can pass from one tonal centre to another, even if only briefly. Do you aim to identify each of these centres, or only the main tonal centre? The main one may well be the root of the final chord, as happens in the video you shared.
I would suggest training with simple excerpts, that stay in one key (like some children's songs) And I would suggest using your voice.
For instance, while listening to such an excerpt you could sing a scale up and down, using only notes that don't clash badly with the excerpt. Just use a syllable like "la" or "da", don't aim to name the notes.
If you manage, with your voice, to find the notes of the major or minor scale being used in the excerpt, you could then pause the audio and sing up and down that scale until you hit the one that sounds "final". That should be the tonal centre. You could then use an instrument (or instrument tuner app on a cell phone) to identify that note.
As you become accustomed to doing that, you may find that, when listening to more complex music (like that in the video) you can hear when the tonal centre shifts. You can then try to identify when the music is using the main one, and use your voice to isolate that one.

How do you go about finding music in various keys that stays in a single key to practice with? Isn’t most children music simply written in C major? And how do you verify the key you found is correct? I don’t trust my ears at all.

Music for beginners on the piano may tend to be written in C major. But recorded children's songs will vary as to key.

But you don't need to practise finding the Tonic of tunes in all keys. If, like me, you don't have perfect pitch, you won't know the name of the Tonic note. You'll just know its sound. As I wrote before, naming the Tonic is a separate step unless you have perfect pitch!

Got it! I’ll try to find simple music to practice with

Learning to identify notes by function rather than by absolute pitch or by interval (with the previous note) is what I found to be most natural.
The tonic function is the easiest to identify. It's the most stable function, you could conclude a phrase or piece with it leaving no tension behind.
That's the best way I could describe it with words, you'll develop your own feel for it if you train to recognize notes and chords by function (their degree in the key).
Look up "Functional Ear Trainer" on iOS and Android. I'm not affiliated, in fact I published my own competing app at one point, but since I wasn't maintaining it, it got taken down after a while.

I’ve actually been working with this app for about a week now. I think I do reasonably well with it (~90% accuracy for random major scales in many octaves) but I find that once I need to use my ears in context when there’s an actual song my accuracy drops to an abysmal level. I started practicing identifying scale degrees in nursery rhymes by transcribing them with no instrument.

@HNHN this is normal, your % accuracy in the app won't directly translate to % accuracy in practice because:
Speed is key!
I used to use an old desktop version of the app, with some custom modifications (incl. keyboard input) and I used to answer multiple notes per second with a 98%+ accuracy. In practice my accuracy still lagged behind, but I got noticeably better.
You need a lot of patience, this isn't something you can master in a few sessions.
You're on the right track!
Pro tip: pick a key and stick to it for 100 notes, so you don't wait for the cadence to play

Also @HNHN props for using a piece of paper and not your instrument, that allows you not to use your reflexes or rely on interval identification. Intervals are useful, but degrees are more important. In practice I do still use intervals so determine whether the next note is adjacent or not in the scale, but I don't think that's all that necessary. I feel it is somewhat of a shortcut. For any intervals larger than seconds degrees feel much easier than intervals.

thanks! Intervals are so much harder for me. It’s actually hard for me to identify stepwise motion. I’m reading Karpinski’s “Aural Skills Acquisition” now and he says that the best transcribers have an arsenal of techniques they use depending on the situation, so they rely both on intervals and degrees in different contexts - pretty much what you describe.

Cool @HNHN, I might actually pick up that book! People go on and on about absolute pitch and interval identification, not enough people talk about degree identification.

Just linking an 8 minute video isn't helpful. What specific point in the video don't you understand?
I scanned through the video and I'm not sure if it is really the best tutorial to use. I say this because tonal center is a fairly clear technical idea and I would rather have a tutorial that just gets to the technical point.
The long and short of it is cadences (or cadential harmony) define tonality. Playing and singing cadences in all keys is a direct way to develop your ear for cadences.
You can play cadences in "classical" or jazz styles. You could also practice "modal" cadences to broaden the range of tonalities to become familiar with.
Some people seem to recoil at the word "cadence" because they associate it with "classical" music. But many pop and jazz songs are structurally and tonally defined by cadences. Granted a lot of pop/rock/jazz uses non-cadential harmony, but you can change your approach for that kind of music. You would probably focus on a central chord vamp, or melodic resting notes at the end of phrases, where the chord root will be the tonic, or the melody will rest on some pitch of the tonic chord.

...to hear [identify] the tonal center of a musical excerpt?

You should ask yourself what exactly the goals is. Do you want to be able to sing the pitch? Name the pitch? Identify the moment to tonal center becomes clear? Are you only interested in the aural skill or also doing it by reading scores? Those are all different and you could practice them in different ways.

...I am often on the road and trying to find ways to leverage flights and waiting times for quick ear training.

This could be tricky. If you're waiting in an airport, you probably can't sing practice patterns out loud. You probably won't have an instrument to sing along with.
There are many ear training apps. There is a huge variety when it comes to the specific exercises they offer. You probably want one that will test identifying cadence types like perfect or half, tonalities like major or minor, scale degrees like whether the melody ended on the tonic, dominant, mediant, etc. and chord qualities.
Another technical approach to be thinking about is solfege. That's the DO RE MI... syllables for scale degrees. Certain patterns like TI DO or FA MI are really important in tonal harmony... in many different styles of music. A training approach that embraces that should be helpful.
For this goal of tonal training avoid apps that just present random intervals, chord types, etc. one after another. I've seen many such apps and never found them helpful. Tonal music isn't random so you want an app that some series of elements that are actually related to a tonal center. But ideally it should change tonal center too.
When your locations allows you to sing, definitely reinforce ear training with an app with actual singing.

To give more context - I am working on ear training and I find it very difficult as I don’t have very good ears, so I try to break complex tasks into smaller digestible aural skills and practice them throughout my day. Specifically, I find it difficult to identify and sing back the tonal center even for simple cadences (I-IV-V-I). My original question was about apps that can help me practice this specifically (without me having to prepare a bunch of training materials which I cannot do at the moment).

One effective way I found to practice this is to use the list of media files in wikipedia. I listen to a short musical excerpt for a piece where the key is given (i.e “Giovanni Giuseppe Cambini - Quintet No. 3 in F major”), try to identify the tonic aurally and then verify that I landed on the right note using a midi keyboard app.

Beware: this doesn't always work. You have to find the key of the movement, not the full multi-movement piece (e.g. the 2nd movement of Beethoven's Symphony No. 5 in C Minor is in A flat major instead), and then you have to sample from the beginning of the piece in order to maximize the chance that the excerpt's tonic is the same as its label (many minor-key pieces end in the tonic major instead, the middles of sonata-allegros/minuet and trios/scherzo and trios are rarely in the same key as the beginning).

@Dekkadeci that’s good to know, I’ll keep it in mind. I guess trying to figure out why I made a mistake when I do is also a good exercise.
